# Create redirect to Edit page need to force reload

Tags: admin-on-rest

I created a Create page which upload a csv file then redirect to Edit.

The API is processes the File and add CSV fields list to the entry.

The problem is when I hit Save and get redirected to Edit, the Edit page does not have the Fields input in record prop.

Reloading the page I'm redirected force the reload so I can see the Fields.

I wonder If I can force the API reload when redirecting?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution...
I just need to process record fields as if they could be undefined.
So that way the Edit page will show and then be refreshed with the API replied record.